# curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake in Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.4)

Tags: git, macos, ssl, bitbucket

When I run this command:

```
git clone <bitbucket repo>.git
```

I get the error:

> fatal: unable to access
>   '.git/': Server
>   aborted the SSL handshake

When I run the command:

```
git --version
```

Output:

> git version 2.9.2

I am unable to understand if the problem is with the **git** installed in my Mac or with my Mac.

Answer (score 5):

Got it. 
This was because I was behind a proxy and this wasn't set as environment variable in command line (thought it was set in System Preferences -> Network -> LAN)

Add these 2 lines in **~/.bashrc** file if you are behind a proxy:

```
export http_proxy=http://<proxy_url>:<proxy_port>/
export https_proxy=https://<proxy_url>:<proxy_port>/
```